# Is the View or the ViewModel responsible for transforming data from a Model to be presented in the UI?

Tags: android, google-maps, design-patterns, mvvm, viewmodel

I am new to MVVM pattern, and this is a general question for me but I will use a specific example.

I have:

- A data class `Place` which contains latitude, longitude, name etc.
- A `MapsViewModel` which contains a places list `LiveData<List<Place>>` used by the `MapsFragment`
- And a `MapsFragment` which represents the `View` of the MVVM pattern.

From my understanding the `View` should be oblivious of the `Model`, in this case `MapsFragment` should not know about the `Place` model.

I want to populate the Map with markers but markers need latitude and longitude (and other parameters such as name etc.) so i should observe the list of places and map each entry in the list to the marker for it.

I am not sure if I should place the code for mapping places to markers inside a `MapsViewModel` so that `MapsFragment` can just call `mapsViewModel.getMarkers()` and use that marker list to populate the map,
or should the `MapsFragment` observe the `mapsViewModel.getPlaces()` and from the response map the list to markers and then populate the map.

If the `MapsViewModel` is supposed to be responsible for mapping places how will I observe the changes on the `LiveData` if new locations are added?

If the `MapsFragment` is supposed to be responsible for mapping then doesn't that break the MVVM pattern where `Views` should not know about the model?

The example is written in `Kotlin` but i did not tag the question with `Kotlin` because it is not language specific.

In my current implementations I am observing the places `LiveData<List<Place>>`

```
// MapsFragment
...
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mapsViewModel.getPlaces().observe(this, Observer { places ->
        places?.forEach { place ->
            var options = MarkerOptions()
            options.position(LatLng(place.lat.toDouble(), place.lon.toDouble()))
            mMap.addMarker(options)
        }
    })
}
...
```

```
// MapsViewModel
...
fun getPlaces(): LiveData<List<Place>> {
    return Repositories.placesRepository.getPlaces()
}
...
```

P.S.
One side question for the ListViews and other collection types: 
Should every cell have its own `ViewModel` or should the whole ListView have only one `ViewModel`?

Comment: No your `ListViews` shouldn't have any `ViewModel` because they have adapters, and `listviews` data comes from the same `ViewModel` that fragment has

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVVM architecture, `ViewModel` exposes stream of data relevant to the `View`. So your `View` should definitely observe the list of `Place`.

> If the MapsFragment is supposed to be responsible for mapping then
>   doesn't that break the MVVM pattern where Views should not know about
>   the model?

We are good, as long as `View` is not directly interacting/changing the data layer (`Model`) and getting all displayable information from `ViewModel` only.

General rule of thumb is,
Data stream exposed by `ViewModel` should be simple enough to be directly consumed by the `View`.

Hope that answers your question.